# Why i'm getting compile time error in actual and formal argument in java?

Tags: java, methods

> I'm getting compile time error when i'm calling the method and pass actual argument
>   as **short** datatype to formal argument of **byte** datatype...

```
display((short)(20));

static void display(byte b1){}
```

But when i pass actual argument as of **byte** datatype to formal argument of **short** datatype then the program compiled successfully..

```
display((byte)(20));

static void display(short b1){}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fit a pint of water in a litre jug; you can't fit a litre of water in a pint jug.

`short` and `byte` are different data types. The range of `short` is `-32768..32767`; the range of `byte` is `-128..127`. Everything that fits in a `byte` also fits in a `short`; but not everything that fits in a `short` can fit into a byte.

Because of this, you can pass a `byte` to a method expecting a `short` (using an implicit [widening primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)), but you can't pass a `short` to a method expecting a `byte`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because short is a "larger" datatype than a byte. A byte is 8 bits, while short is 16 bits in size. When you try to pass an integer literal that is explicitly cast to a short to a method that accepts a byte, Java knows that lossy conversion could take place and displays an error at compile time.

Since byte datatypes are smaller than short datatypes, numeric promotion automatically takes place and the byte is automatically promoted to short in your second example.

Comment: display((byte)(20)); static void display(char b1){} then why i'm getting error in this even byte is of 1 Byte (lower) and char is 2 Byte(higher).

Comment: @Rahulsingh the range of `byte` is -128..127; the range of `char` is 0..65535. `char` can't represent negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

the things you did it its like putting 2 litter of water in a bottle that can contain just 1 litter, so the **byte** datatype that you assumed to your method have a range of number that is smaller than the range of **short** datatype. **byte** can contain a value that can represented by 8 bit but **short** can represent a value of 16 bit.